# How to instantiate FormSet with objects

Tags: python, django

I tried looking in [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) to see if I could find a similar parameter to instance in ModelForm but I could not make it work.

```
class RequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False

OfferItemFormSet = formset_factory(OfferItemForm, formset=RequiredFormSet)
```

## Forms.py

```
class OfferItemForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = OfferItem
    exclude = ('offer', 'item_code', 'type')
    [...]
```

## Views.py

```
i = OfferItem.objects.filter(offer=o).values()
item_formset = OfferItemFormSet(queryset=i)
```

I always `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'`. I tried to change from formset_factory to modelformset_factory but still the same problem.

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "[...]/filter_decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  13.                 return a_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "[...]/views.py" in manage_offer
  1330.         item_formset = OfferItemFormSet(queryset=i)
File "[...]/forms.py" in __init__
  197.             super(RequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /my/offer/add/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'
```

Why is it such a big deal? Why isn't there an instance= parameter on the constructor method of the formset just like a ModelForm has?

## Edit: Using modelformset_factory()

```
OfferItemFormSet = modelformset_factory(OfferItem, form=OfferItemForm, formset=RequiredFormSet)
```

## Forms.py

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

class RequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False
```

## Views.py

```
i = OfferItem.objects.filter(offer=o)
item_formset = OfferItemFormSet(queryset=i)

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query set'
Exception Location: [...]/forms.py in __init__, line 198
```

## Resolution

After changing `BaseFormSet` to `BaseModelFormSet` AND adding `{{ form.id }}` to my loop when generating the formset in the template.

Comment: show more of the error... `__init__` of what class?  the docs here look very close to what you're doing https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a ModelFormset, and `modelformset_factory`, if you want to work with model objects.

Comment: Then you need to show your updated code and the new traceback.

Comment: OKay, I have added it.

Comment: Your RequiredFormSet needs to inherit from BaseModelFormSet.

Comment: It worked, but when I try to submit the form I get `Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value: 
"u'form-0-id'"`.